# How to make DataJpaTest flush save automatically?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an `Employee` entity with the following column:

```
@Entity
class Employee {
  @Column(name = "first_name", length = 14)
  private String firstName;
```

and I have a Spring JPA Repository for it:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {
```

In `test/resources/application.properties` I have the following so that I use an in-memory h2 database with tables auto-generated:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

I was expecting this test to fail, since the `firstName` is longer than what is allowed:

```
@DataJpaTest
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

  @Test
  public void mustNotSaveFirstNameLongerThan14() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setFirstName("koraykoraykoray");  // 15 characters!
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
  }
}
```

And I was surprised to see this test was not failing, however the following does fail:

```
@DataJpaTest
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

  @Test
  public void testMustNotSaveFirstNameLongerThan14() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setFirstName("koraykoraykoray");  // 15 characters!
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
    employeeRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

with the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Value too long for column "FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(14)": "'koraykoraykoray' (15)"; SQL statement:
```

The only difference is the second test has the additional `employeeRepository.findAll();` statement, which forces Hibernate to flush as far as I understand.

This does not feel right to me, I would much rather want the test to fail immediately for `save`.

I can also have

```
@Autowired
private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;
```

and call

```
testEntityManager.flush();
```

but again, this does not *feel* correct either.. How do I make this test fail without any workaround or additional statements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest option in your case is configure `@Transactional` annotation, forcing to send database all changes in your tests (it can be used only in specific ones):

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@DataJpaTest
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

  @Test
  public void mustNotSaveFirstNameLongerThan14() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(1);
    employee.setFirstName("koraykoraykoray");  // 15 characters!
    assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class, () -> {
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
    });
  }

  @Test
  public void mustSaveFirstNameShorterThan14() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(1);
    employee.setFirstName("koraykor");  // 8 characters!
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
  }
}
```

**PD:** I have added a simple `Integer` property as PK of `Employee` entity due to your repository definition.

You can see the results in the following picture:

[image: Reposity tests]

Comment: Thanks, but this is only partially helpful. I actually want to do `assertThatThrownBy(() -> employeeRepository.save(employee)).isInstanceOf(DataIntegrityViolationException.class);` so committing after test method is executed is too late.

Comment: @KorayTugay I have updated my answer with a suitable solution for this case allowing: **1.** Keep `CurdRepository` (you can change to `JpaRepository` if you prefer), **2.** Do not lose internal Hibernate optimizations (not forcing `flush` operation neither in test nor "real code"), **3.** All changes will be sent immediately to database only in specific tests (or in all of them if you keep `@Transactional` in the class definition)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks doctore for your answer, I had the similar problem as OP and your solution has helped. I decided to dig a little and figure out why it works, should someone else have this problem.

With `@DataJpaTest` annotated test class, your class implicitly becomes `@Transactional` with default propagation type `Propagation.REQUIRED`. That means every test method is also `@Transactional` with same default configuration. Now, all CRUD methods in `CrudRepository` are also `@Transactional`, but it has nothing to do with `@DataJpaTest` - they are transactional due to implementation. Whoa, that's a lot of transactions!

As soon as you annotate your whole class (or just a test method) with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)`, your test method(s) are no longer `@Transactional`. However, inner methods of your test method(s), that is, CRUD operations from `CrudRepository`, remain transactional, meaning that they will have their own transaction scopes. Because of that, they will be committed to database immediately after execution, because by default (in **Spring Boot**, which users HikariCP connection pool), auto commits are turned on. Auto commits happen after every SQL query. And thus tests pass as you'd expect.

I like to visualize things, so here is the visualization of the whole process:
[image: so-63782195]

I hope this was helpful. URLs from the diagram:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit
- https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#L126
- https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-transactions-tutorial-understanding-tr (not from diagram, but explains transaction very well!)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `JpaRepository<T,ID>` instead of `CrudRepository<T,ID>`. Something like:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>
```

Then you can use its `saveAndFlush()` method anywhere you need to send data immediately:

```
@Test
public void mustNotSaveFirstNameLongerThan14() {
  Employee employee = new Employee();
  employee.setFirstName("koraykoraykoray");  // 15 characters!
  employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(employee);
}
```

And in code where you would like to have optimization you still can use `save()` method.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks. I wonder if it is possible with a `CrudRepository`..

Comment: @KorayTugay I'm afraid it's not. CrudRepository doesn't allow to control the moment when commands are sent to DB. On the one hand it gets rid developers of details of optimization. On the other hand we can't say when commands will be applied. Anyway, if you find good solution feel free to share it here. )

Answer (score 2):

The `@Commit` can do the job ( it was added since 4.2)

```
  @Test
  @Commit
  public void mustNotSaveFirstNameLongerThan14() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(1);
    employee.setFirstName("koraykoraykoray");  // 15 characters!
    assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class, () -> {
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
    });
  }
```